# how to get JScrollPane scrollbars to appear when client's preferred size changes?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When changing the preferred size of a JTable inside a JScrollPane, the JScrollPane doesn't update its scrollbars appropriately even though the `AS_NEEDED` policy is set for both vertical and horizontal scrollbars.  How do I get the scroll pane to update its scrollbars?

The code below will show that the JTable's preferred size changes but the JScrollPane doesn't ever add scrollbars.

Here's my SSCCE... although the "correct" part is in question:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class jTableResizeWidthInScrollPane {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        JTable table = new JTable();
        final TimesTableModel timesTableModel = new TimesTableModel();
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
                timesTableModel.setMaxNumber(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        table.revalidate();
                        System.out.println(
                            "preferred width: "+
                            table.getPreferredSize().getWidth()
                        );
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        table.setModel(timesTableModel);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(textField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static class TimesTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private int max = 10;

        public int getRowCount() {
            return max;
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return max;
        }

        public void setMaxNumber( int max ) {
            this.max = max;
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return (row+1)*(col+1);
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return String.valueOf(col);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Call invalidate, probably on the JTable, but maybe JScrollPane. It's also possible that the JTable will ignore setPreferredSize, instead relying on the information from the ColumnModel instead, but I don't have the code in front of me

Comment: I tried invalidate on JScrollPane and JTable, both.  I tried with one call first and the other.  Didn't work.  There is a java tutorial that says to call `revalidate` on the client (JTable in this case).  That doesn't work either, as you can see that was my first attempt.

Comment: I'd also take a look at [setAutoResizeMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode(int)) and turn it off. I'm not seeing anywhere that you're actually setting the preferredSize, which is good, you should be letting the information from the TableModel and ColumnModel do the work for you

Comment: Well this is interesting... using my example above, `setAutoResizeMode` does not fix anything.  But in my production environment, where a few things are different (e.g., the layout manager, headers, etc.), this solves my problem!  I'm not sure what's different in production and in this example that makes the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things

1. You add the `JTable` to your frame when you should be adding the `JScrollPane`
2. You should try using `setAutoResizeModel` on the `JTable` and setting it to something like `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`

Something like...

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Well... I feel stupid.  The answer to my problem is the setAutoResizeMode to off, but in my example I didn't even construct the problem correctly by adding the table to the JFrame instead of adding the scrollpane to the JFrame.  Good catch!  Also, all the invalidate/revalidate calls are unnecessary.